# R is a commutative ring with $1\ne 0$ and $R^m \cong R^n$, then $m=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> If $R$ is a commutative ring with $1\ne 0$ and $R^m \cong R^n$ as direct sums of $R$-modules, then $m=n$.

There is a hint to this problem (I don't know how to use it): *Reduce this to the case of a field*.

I noticed that there was [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433996/if-m-is-either-noetherian-or-artinian-and-mn-cong-mm-then-m-n). But as a beginner of commutative algebra, I don't know if my question is closely related to that one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Localize at an arbitrary prime.

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359326/prove-that-mathbb-zn-is-not-isomorphic-to-mathbb-zm-for-m-neq-n/1359343#1359343

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of the other two. The one from AM assumes they're isomorphic as rings, this one assumes they're isomorphic as $R$-modules, which makes for a very simple proof.

Comment: @RobertCardona: I don't see anything in this question or either of the duplicates saying that they are isomorphic as rings, as opposed to as modules.

Comment: @EricWofsey the first one is referencing AM 2.11 which assumes they are isomorphic as rings (which is what makes the problem challenging); you're right about the second one. Let me remove my vote to reopen! My bad!

Comment: @RobertCardona: Oh, huh, the original version of the first linked duplicate was asking about rings rather than modules, but it has since been edited to talk about modules instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asume $R^m \cong R^n$ as $R$-modules. $\mathfrak{m} \subset R$ be a maximal ideal, $R/\mathfrak{m}$ the residue field.

Tensoring with $R/\mathfrak{m}$, we get $R^m \otimes R/\mathfrak{m} \cong R^n \otimes R/\mathfrak{m}$, hence $R^m/\mathfrak{m} R^m \cong R^n/\mathfrak{m} R^n$. Both of these are finite dimensional vector spaces over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ of dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Hence, by classification of finite dimensional vector spaces, $m = n$.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: @user26857 I thought the point of voting system was to evaluate answers based on it's quality? Besides, when I posted the answer, the question was not yet marked as a duplicate, so I did not know (although suspected) that this proof had appeared before in MSE. Otherwise I would not have answered it and would have voted to close as duplicate, of course.